# What happens when I create a Nether portal in the End?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I go to the End, and bring the things I need to create a portal with me, where will my portal to the Nether go? Will it even spawn at all?

**New Edit:** SPC has a command called `spawnportal` I tried it once and it created a fully functional portal, but what will happen when I go through it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As has already been said, you cannot build a portal in the End.

However, they can still be hacked in and used. Using creative mode and INVEdit, I located a naturally spawning End portal frame, and traveled to the End. From there, I placed a portal block and traveled to the Nether. Finally, I placed another portal block and was spawned back on the Overworld.

End Portal: (-1007,16,-123); 
End Spawn: (100,53,0); 
Nether Portal: (89,64,-21); 
Nether Spawn: (11,62,-3); 
Overworld Portal: (8,46,20); 
Overworld Spawn: (74,64,163);

Note than when I spawned in the Nether, I was inside other blocks and no Overworld portal spawned with me. Spawning back to the overworld worked fine.

Comment: "no overworld portal spawned w/ me" is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @fireDude67 If you're in a serious game, you should probably avoid going from the End to the Nether. It would be easily possible to suffocate, or even spawn in lava.

Answer (score 12):

Nether portals created in The End will simply not activate when you ignite them.

**Response to New Edit**

I have no clue, but I would suggest backing up your world before trying it. It is possible that you won't be able to go through the portal and you will just stand there.

Comment: You mean that once you put in all the obsidian in place and give fire to it, nothing happens? Or do you mean the portal seems to activate but nothing happens as you stand inside it?

Comment: When you give fire to it, nothing will happen.

Comment: Etho [recently confirmed this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2WiM68WbgU#t=15m15s) on camera.

Answer (score 1):

you will have an obsidian frame with fire inside.

Comment: He's talking about spawning an *already lit* portal.